# how to wrap form elements within the div tag(with background-color) using twitter bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to twitter bootstrap. I was trying to include all the form elements inside the div tag and fill it with some background-color in CSS and align it properly and this is working fine but I am loosing the responsive nature of the div tag along with form elements. can anyone help me with this?

The following is my index.html page.

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="bg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 " id="main">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="submit" role="form" action="create_leads.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lname"> Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="focusedInput" placeholder="Please enter your name" required /> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mobile"> phone-number: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="please enter your phone number" required/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The following is my CSS code

```
body{

        background: gray url('../images/bg8.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-position: fixed;
        background-size: 100% auto;

 }

 #main  {
        position:absolute;
        border: 5px solid gray;
        background-color: gray;
        opacity: 0.8;
        margin: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
    }
```

Comment: On `#main` remove all your margins. That is going to really mess with the responsive code bootstrap has in place.

Comment: thank you it worked! but is there any other alternate way to bring down the div and all the form elements to the center of the page?

Comment: 'align it properly' what do you mean? horizontally align #main to #bg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to center the login inside the very center of the page here's an easy example on how to do it.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj3kyakv/1/)**

You didn't need to embed the column inside an embedded row but just use the first one. You can tinker with the `col` width and `col-md-offset` to get the width of your box the way you want it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's working fine for me but need one more advice. when i am placing my logo on top of the page; for the full-size window its working fine but when I am re-sizing the window to small width of tablet and phone,  the form elements are overlapping with the logo. can you help me with that? Here is the code in fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/dasariyeshwant/rw57ycuy/

Comment: Already I cleaned it up a bit for you. You had some `row`s embedded in `row`s and excess `col` that you didn't really need. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/809j5130/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you're trying to center the form in the middle of the page. You can use the "transform" technique. Don't forget to add prefixes ('-webkit-, etc').

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

You'd want to get rid of all the div's surrounding the "#main" element, since bootstrap won't really care about "container" and "row", etc when using absolute positioning and nothing else is on the page. The "transform" CSS will literally take the "#main" and put it in the center of the page, kind of like a modal.

```
<body>
    <div id="main" class="col-md-9">
        // your form
    </div>
</body>
```

Additionally, since you're new to bootstrap, if you have the class "col-md-9", there's no reason to add "col-xs-9" since on that viewport width it cannot use the "col-md-9"'s width. You can just leave it as only "col-md-9" only, and remove the "col-xs-9".

Note: the "transform" CSS only works for modern browsers.

**Edit:**

You actually do need the "row" and container class applied since you have floating elements inside the "#main" element, and therefore it will not clear for padding, margins, etc. The "container" class will give you that padding on the edges that you need for mobile views

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="main" class="col-md-9">
                // your form
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```